# Least singular value of triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix of this form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a_1 &a_2 & ... & a_n \\
0 & 1 & a_1  & ... & a_{n-1} \\
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

where $0<a_i\le C < 1.$  I want to bound from below the least singular value of this matrix.

This matrix is upper triangular, so it is not difficult to compute its inverse, and in particular, from that operation we get that all the elements of the inverse are bounded by $nC$, so that the least sincular value is

$$\sigma_1(A) = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|_2}\ge \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|_F} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3} C}.$$

where $F$ denotes the Frobenius norm, which bounds the $2-$norm of a matrix.

However, I find this bound very loose, is it possble to do something better?

EDIT:
The computing there is not correct. As crazy as it may seem, I have just found that, for $C=0.9$, a seqeuence of matrices $A_n$ of dimension $n$ with
$$\sigma_1(A_n) \approx e^{-Cn/2}$$